# use of undeclared identifier 'sqrt'?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my C++11 code I have:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "Matrix.h"

#define DEPENDENCY_VERBOSE

using namespace mtm;
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::pair;
using std::ostream;
```

But when I write:

```
double x=sqrt(5);
```

I get:

> use of undeclared identifier 'sqrt'

How to fix this?

Comment: You need `#include <cmath>`

Comment: If you get two equivalent answers, it's customary to accept the one that was posted first. If you decided to not do that because you thought Mickaël downvoted the question, he didn't do that; the downvote is mine.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to

```
#include <cmath>
```

sqrt is defined in cmath header.

Comment: Thanks, did you downvote my question cause I got blocked?

Comment: @Jobert I didn't downvote it